# RadTabStrip.Net2.dll assembly is not found

Tags: telerik

I recently installed asp.Net Ajax control toolkit. But in my program files /telerik folder i didnt find RadTabStrip.Net2.dll. But i Have Telerik.Web.UI.dll and Telerik.Web.Design.dll. I just installed trail version. For trail version do we get RadTabStrip.Net2.dll. Please elt me know. Its urgent.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the Telerik.Web.UI assembly, then you do not need the RadTabStrip.Net2 one. The Telerik.Web.UI contains a newer version of the tabstrip/multipage controls. Change the

```
<%@ Register Assembly="RadTabStrip.Net2"  Namespace="Telerik.WebControls" TagPrefix="RadTS"  %>
```

to

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI"  Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="RadTS"  %>
```

and add a script manager to your page. For more information about the migration to Telerik.Web.UI, see [Migrating from classic tabstrip to the ASP.NET AJAX version](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/tab_overviewmigrating.html)